# Kali linux keep getting unmet dependencies libc6-dev-i386

Tags: kali-linux

I have tried to purge it and reinstall but it still give me the same error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libc6-dev-i386' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gcc-6-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going 
to be installed
libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.24-9) but it is not going 
to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages 
(or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the recommended command `apt --fix-broken install`?
What other package do you use that uses this one?
Did you try a different architecture version of this package (like amd64)?

It seems more like you installed the packages that have unmet dependencies manually, which probably means, your particular system needs either a different set of packages for your needs or a different version of those you downloaded.

Comment: yar i did try it but it still cant work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix. Personally I would remove any packages giving you issues and reinstall the program or package.

```
dpkg --purge --force-depends "gcc-multilib"

dpkg --purge --force-depends "libc6-dev-x32"
```